# Switching apps/screens in Steam

Tags: steam

In my previous incarnation as a Mint and Windows user I could switch to the main desktop when using steam with a simple key combo, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. I was playing a game on elementary OS via Steam for the first time last week and needed to get to the main desktop but no key kombo worked.  Can someone tell me how please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try the workspace navigation shotcuts, like Super(Windows)+left.

The following issue might be relevant: https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/131

Comment: Will test your suggestion with super and left.